# Install .NET Runtime on .NET Core 3.1 Nano Server Docker Image

Tags: .net-core, docker-run, nano-server

I have a .NET Core 3.1 console app that uses the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` project SDK because it references `Geometry3D` in `System.Windows.Media.Media3D`.

I would like to run this in a Docker container on Windows Nano Server, but I receive the following error when executing `docker run`:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

**How do I go about installing the required sdk and runtime?**

Here is my existing Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["HelloWpfCore/HelloWpfCore.csproj", "HelloWpfCore/"]
RUN dotnet restore "HelloWpfCore/HelloWpfCore.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/HelloWpfCore"
RUN dotnet build "HelloWpfCore.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "HelloWpfCore.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HelloWpfCore.dll"]
```

GitHub repo is here: https://github.com/tonysneed/hello-netcore-wpf-nano

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I created an image that installs the Windows Desktop runtime on Nano Server base image.

```
# escape=`

# Installer image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909 AS installer

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Retrieve .NET Core Runtime
# USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN $dotnet_version = '3.1.5'; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile dotnet-installer.exe https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/86835fe4-93b5-4f4e-a7ad-c0b0532e407b/f4f2b1239f1203a05b9952028d54fc13/windowsdesktop-runtime-3.1.5-win-x64.exe; `
    $dotnet_sha512 = '5df17bd9fed94727ec5b151e1684bf9cdc6bfd3075f615ab546759ffca0679d23a35fcf7a8961ac014dd5a4ff0d22ef5f7434a072e23122d5c0415fcd4198831'; `
    if ((Get-FileHash dotnet-installer.exe -Algorithm sha512).Hash -ne $dotnet_sha512) { `
        Write-Host 'CHECKSUM VERIFICATION FAILED!'; `
        exit 1; `
    }; `
    `
    ./dotnet-installer.exe /S

# Runtime image 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1909

ENV `
    # Enable detection of running in a container
    DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true

# In order to set system PATH, ContainerAdministrator must be used
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\dotnet"
USER ContainerUser

COPY --from=installer ["/Program Files/dotnet", "/Program Files/dotnet"]
```

I pushed this to my repo on Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/tonysneed/dotnet-runtime-windowsdesktop

Then I simply used this custom image as the base image for my sample app: https://github.com/tonysneed/hello-netcore-wpf-nano